# struts2. add path to url

Tags: url, struts2

I'm working with struts2.
An external app calls to my app with url

```
http://localhost:8080/present/jsp/mi.action?cod=02021
```

But because of my JSP file system, my action result is in

```
http://localhost:8080/present/jsp/ALTE/mi.action?cod=02021
```

(note the difference in ALTE).

The JSP has some lines as

```
<%@ include file="../comuns/comunCssyJs.jsp"%>
```

The first ../ is to go out ALTE.
If I access with first link the page is loaded but no include files are found. However, with second link there is no problem.

Does someone know what can I do? I know I can change my JSP-s dir-s, but I'd prefer to "add automatically" the ALTE path to the url. is that possible?

Thanks in advance.
Jon

Comment: Put an absolute path to `comunCssyJs.jsp` like `/WEB-INF/ALTE/comuns/comunCssyJs.jsp`.

Comment: Wow, that does actually work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Struts2 `<s:include>` tag http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/include.html with `<s:url>` tag http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/url.html.